# Android Google TTS - select voice variant programmatically

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice

Google TTS voices on Android, at least for some language/country pairs, come with male and female variants - for example English United Kingdom, has both low and high quality male and female voices. Yet the Google TTS engine, when enumerating voices with TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA intent, lists only language-country locales, without the variant, e.g. eng-gbr, eng-usa.

When calling the tts.setLanguage(locale), I tried adding the variant like "eng-gbr-male" or "eng-gbr-Male", but they ignore this, always returning the value 1 (language and region available, variant not). Is there any way to set the male or female variant programmatically for Google TTS voices, from a normal app without a root access?

Greg

Comment: This question has been asked a couple of times, so far nobody seems to know of a way around it. For whatever reason, the service isn't exposing those variants for use. Maybe licensing issues with particular devices?

Comment: @Turnsole, thank you! I'm very disappointed with the poor quality of programmatic support Google TTS provides, and also with a long time their high quality voices take each to initialize - on Note 3 at least 6 seconds for each HQ voice. To a user it seems like eternity, compared with all other TTS engines I use.

Comment: This is a frustrating issue and there's nowhere for us to report problems or suggestions. I emailed Google from the link in the Play Store asking them to open a dedicated area in their Product Forums, but the chances of hearing back from them or it happening, are zero.

Comment: @brandall, same here, I emailed "the developer" from the Google Play link, complaining about issues like very long init time for their HQ voices, never heard back. On a device with root access we could probably figure this out, but no chance without it.

Comment: @gregko We really need to submit an ASOP enhancement request, to make a change to the dated TTS API, which all Engines will then adhere to. Using locales of eng-GBR-Male is bad design and separate parameters for gender, at the least, would be a good start. I'll return shortly and post the code I use for examining all available engine data

Comment: @brandall, that would be great, thank you! I also list all available engines and voices with TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA intents and some custom code Ivona TTS, which does not do it right with intent data. Another enhancement to Android TTS API that I would like to see, would be notifications/events sent when each word is spoken, to highlight words, needed in learning foreign languages or children educational apps.

Comment: refer my answer it works for me.i can set voice for male.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681232/android-tts-male-voices/49444251#49444251

Answer (score 0):

As of API 21, you can use the TextToSpeech.[setVoice()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#setVoice(android.speech.tts.Voice)) method.