# Android Vocalizer TTS - select voice variant

Tags: android, text-to-speech

This is very similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917260/android-google-tts-select-voice-variant-programmatically)

But with a different engine: Vocalizer TTS (package **es.codefactory.vocalizertts**)

Same as the mentioned question, when enumerating voices with TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA intent, I only get stuff like por-BRA, eng-GBR  and so on.

Since it's a different engine, maybe there's another way of selecting the variant? I have managed to do that with Ivona's and Acapela's engines (and others).

Anyone have experience with this specific TTS engine?

(P.S - I have sent a ticket for support to them, asking this same question... If they do answer, I will post it here)

**Edited (2015/06/15)**

They said:

> This issue is being escalated to the bug tracking system for work in the future version of the applications. Once there is an update to the applicaiton, please check for the resolution of the issues and let us know if works for you or not.

Oh well... guess I have to keep checking realease notes...