# Android TTS male voices

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, google-voice

Is it possible to install and configure some male voices on `android.speech.tts.Voice`? I have read some news that Android had made some available recently, but I can't find or configure any. All the ones that I try with command `tts.setLanguage(Locale.ITALY);` are female.

Comment: refer my answer it works for me.i can set voice for male.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681232/android-tts-male-voices/49444251#49444251

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not at present. An [enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/android/) is needed so that the gender can be included in the [Voice Feature Set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/Voice.html#getFeatures()), such that:

Voice[Name: en-AU-afi-network, locale: en_AU, quality: 500, latency: 400, requiresNetwork: true, features: [networkTimeoutMs, networkRetriesCount, **male**]]

I have sent emails to Text to Speech providers about including this - as waiting for an enhancement from Google is probably years away.

All you can do in the mean time, is hard-code the name of the engine with a reference to the gender. It's time consuming and there's no guarantee that they won't change the name.... Needs must for me.

Comment: do you know what "afi" mean in the voice name?

Comment: @brandall I am creating an application which uses text to speech and I want to use different voice instead of it's default female voice which sounds like robotic. I did R&D on this but couldn't find any way to integrate male voice. I have got all voices from tts.getVoices() and I have hard coded the name of the engine but It doesn't support in some devices

Comment: when i use  Set<String> a=new HashSet<>();
        a.add("male");
        //Voice v=new Voice("en-us-x-sfg#female_2-local",new Locale("en","US"),400,200,true,a);
        Voice v=new Voice("hi-IN-x-sfg#male_2-local",new Locale("hi","IN"),400,200,true,a);
        tts.setVoice(v);
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = tts.setVoice(v); ------------------> it always gives female voice for hi-IN locale , please help me

Answer (score 7):

To enhance @brandall 's answer, It is possible to use male/female voice and change it from App UI dynamically. Define TTS like this (add tts engine in constructor):

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this, "com.google.android.tts");
```

> contex = activity/app
>
> this= TextToSpeech.OnInitListener

From `tts.getVoices()` list, chose your desired voice by it's name like this:

```
for (Voice tmpVoice : tts.getVoices()) {
            if (tmpVoice.getName().equals(_voiceName)) {
                return tmpVoice;
                break;
            }
}
```

N.B: U need to set `_voiceName` by getting hard coded voice_name from `tts.getVoices()`. e.g: for English male it would be: "en-us-x-sfg#male_1-local"

Comment: I have hard coded the name of the engine as you define above but It doesn't support in some devices and speak in default voice. What could be the solution ?

Comment: i want male voice for locale hi,---- >it always gives female voice for hi-IN locale – I used your code to fetch tts.getVoices() and previously it was giving the proper value like => "hi-in-x-cfn#male_3-local"  ,  But now it changes the tts.getVoices() changes the value => Voice[Name: hi-in-x-hia-local, locale: hi_IN, quality: 400, latency: 200,requiresNetwork: false, features: [networkTimeoutMs, networkRetriesCount]] , Please guide me where i am missing ?

Comment: @GyanSwaroopAwasthi Use "hi-in-x-hie-local" in place of _voiceName here. It will give you a male voice.

Answer (score 2):

```
// use this code after onInit success assuming you have initilaised text to speech as tts

Set<Voice> voices = tts.getVoices();
for (Voice tmpVoice : tts.getVoices()) {
    if (tmpVoice.getName().contains("#male") && tmpVoice.getName().contains("en-us")) {
        voice = tmpVoice;
        break;
    }
    else {
        voice = null;
    }
}
if (voice != null) {
    tts.setVoice(voice);
}
```

use this code on after `on_init` gets successful, do a version check because `getVoices()`  got added on API level 21

Comment: In the above solution   if (tmpVoice.getName().contains("#male") && tmpVoice.getName().contains("en-us"))   Never gives true result because tts.getVoice() doesn't contains such things like "male" keywords , Two Days before i get the result for male and female voice but now same code is not working for male , every time female voice and tts.getVoices() gives  Voice[Name: hi-in-x-hia-local, locale: hi_IN, quality: 400, latency: 200,requiresNetwork: false, features: [networkTimeoutMs, networkRetriesCount]]  where i don't get the male voice. Please guide me why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am posting code for select male or female voice using google speech engine.

```
    Set<String> a=new HashSet<>();
    a.add("female");//here you can give male if you want to select mail voice.

    Voice v=new Voice("en-us-x-sfg#female_2-local",new Locale("en","US"),400,200,true,a); 
    myTTS.setVoice(v);
```

Here most take care about Voices name. like "en-us-x-sfg#female_2-local"

You can get all voices by using following method and you can download in file.

```
myTTS.getVoices() // you can get all voices of male female related information which we can set in Voice.whoever voice we want to listen.(male /female.)
```

Comment: what are the default voices support by devices for locale es_ES including male or female? or if device not support, it will install first then use? what could be the solution ?

Comment: it depends on speech engine have voices.otherwise need to install speech engine and particular voices provided by speech engine.

Comment: I have a requirement to speech text in human voice or the voice not to be robotic. Is there any way to achieve ? Is there any default engine for device?

Comment: i want male voice for locale hi,---- > when i use Set<String> a=new HashSet<>(); a.add("male"); //Voice v=new Voice("en-us-x-sfg#female_2-local",new Locale("en","US"),400,200,true,a); Voice v=new Voice("hi-IN-x-sfg#male_2-local",new Locale("hi","IN"),400,200,true,a); tts.setVoice(v); if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) { int result = tts.setVoice(v); ------------------> it always gives female voice for hi-IN locale , please help me –

Answer (score 0):

I found 3 Male voices in google tts

1. en-in-x-ene-network
2. en-in-x-end-network
3. hi-in-x-hie-local

Use these in the following way:
`textToSpeechEngine.voice = Voice("hi-in-x-hie-local", Locale("hi_IN"), 400, 200, false, HashMap<String>())`