# Android TextToSpeech, change gender voices

Tags: java, android, google-text-to-speech

I am about to try to make an application that when you pass by params a language and a type of voice (male or female).
I do know the language change, as follows [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setLanguage(java.util.Locale)):

```
tts.setLanguaje(Locale loc)
```

But as I look and read can not I find a way to change the voice for the languages you have available more than one type of voice.

Please help me and Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe download both the required voices?

Comment: I have downloaded several languages, so I have found that there are different types of voices for some languages, but I have no way to program tell me what kinds of voices has that language available to choose female or male

Comment: I guess it's a system setting. You set the voice gender you want and use that.

Comment: But like if I can change the language, I would like to change the code by voice if I had several options
Thanks

Comment: Maybe that setting is not accessible in the current API. Also because you don't know which TTS voices your users did download.

Comment: Related: [The gender isn't specified for TTS voices.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681232/android-tts-male-voices)

Comment: I've seen the method, <http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setVoice(android.speech.tts.Voice)>:
setVoice(Voice voice)
But before you would have to know if there are different types of voices there is where my doubt

Comment: Thanks @MarkusKauppinen I thought I could have advanced, and although gender was not the voice, could give the type and according to those guys and to choose one or the other as gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

US english in android don't support multi gender speaking facility.But UK english can.
First you have to download(if not exist) the Text-to-Speech UK english pack.For that goto setting->Languages and input->click on right icon of prefered engine->Language->UK

Comment: Yes, there are some languages that do not have different voices. But I would like to know how to program in code, as if you have to control different types of voice, and if I had to choose the type of voice.
Thanks