# How to use male voice in text to speech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to let the user select between male or female voice. I tried doing that using tts but no result. All the voices that came with `TextToSpeech` are female.

I have already tried these solutions from here [Android TTS male voices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681232/android-tts-male-voices/52157464)
but no one is working for me. Do you know how could I solve this problem, or could you suggest another option for using male voice also?